# Should i use wsdl or json for my ios app?

Tags: ios, json, soap, wsdl

I am writing an iOS app which will have to fetch some data from a server. Is it better to use WSDL and SOAP to get these data from a web service, or should i use JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is good if you don't have any security stakes. Otherwise, you should use a secured data exchange protocol like SOAP or maybe OAuth.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If you wouldn't have to think about security, which would you prefer? From some searching i have made i see that prefer JSON. Is it "faster"?

Comment: JSON is the best way and in terms of weight, that's better than XML. With iOS you have a class for that : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Honestly where I've worked with JSON alot i would personally recommend it because it's a really easy way to send data and to parse data. If your going to be fetching from a server using mysql or something along those lines I would recommend you go with JSON.